# How I can resize UML diagram in the Microsoft Visio?

Tags: microsoft-visio, uml

I have got a UML Diagram in Microsoft Visio (The size of page is A4). But I can't resize this diagram for A1 format (page size). How I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/264676) Microsoft KB article can help; you could simply resize all the elements in your UML diagram until it fits on an A1 page.

Comment: Could you possibly quote the relevant sections from your link? Please see [answer].